# Issue with saving characters in multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, printf, scanf

i have a given Input of four scanf-strings which i want to save in a multidimensional array. I Don't know if i save the string right, but i can't just simply print the whole array or certain characters of it.

```
char getr[4][4];

    for (z=0; z<4; z++){
    scanf(" %99s", &getr[z]);
    }

    for (s=0; s<4; s++) {
        printf("%s\n",getr[s]);
    }
```

Input:
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

Output:
abcdefghijklmnop
efghijklmnop
ijklmnop
mnop

what if i just want to print the second line or the fourth character of the first line? Does anybody know?

Comment: You need to leave space for a terminating null char (ie. 5 elements for a 4 char string).  Also, don't use `%99s` when you don't have space for a 99 char string.

Answer (score 0):

First, change as following:

```
scanf(" %99s", getr[z]);  //getr[z] is the address to take the 4 characters string
```

To print out the second line:

```
printf("%s\n", getr[1]);
```

To print out the fourth character of the first line:

```
printf("%c\n", getr[0][3]);  // %c is used here because just print one character.
```

Answer (score 0):

To store 4-char strings, like your example input, you need 5-char arrays to leave room for the terminating null character:

```
char getr[4][5];
```

Your `scanf()` format string should also reflect the amount of space you have; `%99s` could read up to 100 bytes (99 chars plus the null), and you only have 5 (including the null, after the above change).  Also, `&getr[z]` and `getr[z]` happen to give the same address, but the types of the pointers are different -- but `getr[z]` gives a `char *` which is appropriate in this case.  So...

```
    scanf(" %4s", getr[z]);
```

Those changes will already keep the strings from running together, so individual strings can be accessed as `getr[0]` through `getr[3]`.  To print individual characters within a string, add an additional set of indexing brackets and use a function that prints a character rather than a string:

```
fputc(getr[0][2],stdout); /* print 3rd char in 1st string */

printf("%c",getr[1][3]); /* print 4th char of 2nd string */
```

The reason you were getting all your strings concatenated was because the null char from the earlier strings overflowed into the next char array, and was overwritten by the first char of the next string you read.  The last string's null would have overflowed past your whole 2D array into whatever was next in memory (which is bad).